# Duplicate entry in adding rows to a table

Tags: mysql

I've been working on trying to add more rows of data to a table I created in MySQL, but every time I do that, an error warning pops up saying that there's a duplicate entry for the second row (the one with the id '2'), and it doesn't receive the two rows I created after that. What should I do?

It happened when I tried doing this:

```
USE airdogs;

INSERT INTO members
VALUES ('2', 'Arnonn Alloband', 'company-captain', 'Strell', 'male', 'Frostbite', '7', '5375-01-04', NULL),
       ('3', 'Kendrow Tellman', 'company-private', 'Strell', 'male', 'Carefersian', '1', '5380-01-09', NULL),
       ('4', 'Barmar Tosceni', 'company-private', 'Ithrenian', 'male', 'Brimstone', '4', '5382-01-11', NULL);
       
SELECT * FROM members;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. To answer this we need to be able to see the table structure as well as the queries you are running against it. Here's some [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE members; for analysis.

Comment: If the all the row data is the same from a previous insert, you could do: `INSERT IGNORE INTO members...`, then only warnings will be generated instead of an error.